# python-docx installation does not work

Tags: python, redhat, python-docx

I'm trying to install python-docx package but get problems...

```
Running setup.py install for lxml
    /opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.3.5.
    Building without Cython.
    ERROR: /bin/sh: xslt-config: command not found

    ** make sure the development packages of libxml2 and libxslt are installed **
```

How do I install libxml2 and libxslt package? I downloaded the package from here `ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/python/`  but get installation problems as given below...

```
[root@1d install]# cd libxml2-python-2.6.9
[root@1d libxml2-python-2.6.9]# dir
drv_libxml2.py          libxml.c       libxsl.py        libxslt-python-api.xml  README    types.c
libxml2-api.xml         libxml.py      libxslt-api.xml  libxslt_wrap.h          setup.py  xmlgenerator.py
libxml2-python-api.xml  libxml_wrap.h  libxslt.c        PKG-INFO                TODO      xsltgenerator.py
[root@1d libxml2-python-2.6.9]# python setup.py install
failed to find headers for libxml2: update includes_dir
```

Comment: Does using `sudo apt-get install libxml2 libxslt1.1` work?

Comment: Im on redhat...not sure of the rpm libraries

Comment: They're probably `libxml2-devel` and `libxslt-devel` or similar then. Don't bother with source packages for them.

Comment: yum install libxml2-devel is not working.."No package libxml2-devel available"

Comment: might find what you need here http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libxml2-devel

Comment: [root@f1d install]# rpm -ivh libxml2-python-2.5.4-1.i386\ \(1\).rpm
warning: libxml2-python-2.5.4-1.i386 (1).rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID db42a60e
error: Failed dependencies:
        libxml2 = 2.5.4 is needed by libxml2-python-2.5.4-1.i386
        libxml2.so.2 is needed by libxml2-python-2.5.4-1.i386

Comment: Where can I get the libxml2=2.5.4?